# RegEx find paragraphs with missing close quote

Tags: c#, regex

I want to find an open quote (“) without a matching close quote (”) before a newline, unless the character after the newline is an open quote. For example:

```
He said, “bla bla bla
She didn't listen.
```

The above should find **"bla bla bla**

However, this next example should NOT match, because the next line starts with an open quote:

```
He said, “bla bla bla
“bla bla bla.”
```

FYI, I'm using C# Regex class. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
“(?>[^\r\n“”]*)(?!\r?\n“)(?!”)
```

will match text from an opening quote to the end of the line, unless there is a closing quote in-between or the next line starts with an opening quote.

Assuming your goal is to fix those lines, i.e., insert a closing quote where necessary,

```
result = Regex.Replace(subject, 
    @"“         # Match an opening quote
    (?>         # Match in an atomic group (no backtracking!):
     [^\r\n“”]* # any characters except newlines or quotes
    )           # End of atomic group
    (?!\r?\n“)  # Assert that no linebreak, followed by an opening quote, follows
    (?!”)       # Assert that no closing quote follows", 
    "$0”", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

will do that.

Comment: Thanks! I marked this as the answer, although I had to add [ and ] around the second occurrence of \r\n, because apparently I don't always have both. So:  “(?>[^\r\n“”]*)(?![\r\n]“)(?!”)

Comment: @DanThomas: In that case, I think `\r?\n` is more robust. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Obviously I'm fairly new to regexes. Why is it more robust?

Comment: @DanThomas: `[\r\n]` matches either a `\r` or a `\n`, but not both. So unless C# internally normalizes all linebreaks to `\n` (like Python does, but I don't know about C# in this regard), `\r?\n` matches a single linebreak in any (reasonably current) OS.

Comment: I didn't know that about [\r\n]. Actually, that probably explains some strange happenings I've seen. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Will something like this work?

```
"[^"]*\n[^"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following powershell example of a universal regex.

`("[^"\n]*)("|\n(?!"))`

## Example

```
    $Matches = @()
    $String = '"bla bla bla
She didn''t listen.
He said, "bla bla bla
"bla bla bla."'
    Write-Host start with 
    write-host $String
    Write-Host
    Write-Host found
    ([regex]'("[^"\n]*)("|\n(?!"))').matches($String) | foreach {
        write-host "key at $($_.Groups[1].Index) = '$($_.Groups[1].Value)'"
        } # next match
```

## Yields

```
start with
"bla bla bla
She didn't listen.
He said, "bla bla bla
"bla bla bla."

found
key at 0 = '"bla bla bla
'
key at 57 = '"bla bla bla.'
```

## Summary

- `("[^"\n]*)` returns all the non ", \n characters from an open double quote
- `("|\n(?!"))`  stops the return when the first ", or \n is encountered
- `(?!")` ensures the \n line just before it is not followed by a double quote

I can't seem to get rid of the new line character on the first match, this might be easier to use a "trim" statement.

Comment: Thanks! However, it's not quite right. I don't want "key at 57" to be found. -The newline character on the first match is OK, so don't worry about that.